# AWS SNS Invalid Token

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am trying to have the endpoint as my website (http://website.com/) and publish to the SNS topic after successful subscription.

No matter what I try, I get the same Invalid Token Error. Can someone help me out? 
(sanitized code)

```
 endPointTest()
  .then((result) => {
    console.log("Result", result);

    AWS.config.update({
      accessKeyId:'accessKeyIdvalue',
      secretAccessKey:'secretAccessKeyvalue',
      region: 'us-west-2'
    });
    var sns = new AWS.SNS();
    console.log("SNS OBj", sns); 
    var params2 = {
      Protocol: 'http', /* required */
      TopicArn: 'topic_ARN_from_console', /* required */
      Endpoint: 'http://website.com/'
    };
    sns.subscribe(params2, function(err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err, err.code); // an error occurred, where it breaks
      else     {
        console.log("Subscribing...", data.ResponseMetadata.RequestId);//Prints this
        console.log("Subscribing... with data", data); //Prints this fine
        var params1 = {
          Token: data.ResponseMetadata.RequestId, /* required */
          TopicArn: 'topic_ARN_from_console' /* required */
          //AuthenticateOnUnsubscribe: 'false'
        };
        sns.confirmSubscription(params1, function(err, data) {
          if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
          else    {
            console.log("Confirmed Sub", data);
          }          // successful response
        });
      }
    });
  }).catch(console.error.bind(console));
```

Error I get:

```
POST https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ 400 (Bad Request)
```

VideoUploader.js:135 Error: Invalid token

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The [SNS subscribe() documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SNS.html#subscribe-property) says that the returned data only contains a SubscriptionArn. It does not contain the confirmation token.

I believe that the subscription confirmation token that you are looking for is sent by SNS to the endpoint that you indicated when you called subscribe(). This is how SNS confirms that you control the endpoint. You need to retrieve it from that endpoint and then provide it back to SNS by calling confirmSubscription().

Comment: Sorry, what endpoint? How can I get it (Do you have a code sample)

Comment: I looked up my this context as well but that didnt seem to help!

Comment: You asked which endpoint. It's your endpoint; the one that you provided in your subscribe() call. The subscribe() call prepares to subscribe your endpoint by sending your endpoint a confirmation token. You then provide that token back to SNS in the confirmSubscription() call. It's a handshake to prove that you control the endpoint and didn't mis-type it, or something similar. See the Subscribe action described at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Subscribe.html.